# MouseDown before MouseMove is always guaranteed in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.Capture(this.eventSource);
    BlockA();
}

void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        BlockB();
}
```

Is it guaranteed BlockA() is always run before BlockB()? I'm using C# under WPF. I encountered a strange bug that only happens at certain systems. I suspect the event order matters, but I couldn't find any literatures regarding this at MSDN. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. If the button is pressed outside your window, then moved inside, then it'll trigger. You should set a boolean to know you caught the mouse down.

Answer (score 4):

`Mouse.Capture(this.eventSource);` causes a `MouseMove` event.

To always execute `BlockA()` before `BlockB()`, change `MouseLeftButtonDown()` to this:

```
void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    BlockA();
    Mouse.Capture(this.eventSource);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the event order for WinForm, but I guess it's the same in WPF  [Mouse Event in Windows Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If you want to handle mouse click events in the proper order, you need to know the order in which click events are raised in Windows Forms controls. All Windows Forms controls raise click events in the same order when a mouse button is pressed and released (regardless of which mouse button), except where noted in the following list for individual controls. The following list shows the order of events raised for a single mouse-button click:
>   MouseDown event.
>   Click event.
>   MouseClick event.
>   MouseUp event.
>
> The order of events raised for a double mouse-button click:
>   MouseDown event.
>   Click event.
>   MouseClick event.
>   MouseUp event.
>   MouseDown event.
>   DoubleClick event.
>   MouseDoubleClick event.
>   MouseUp event.

Comment: Please write up summary in the answer or you post will be likely deleted/converted to comment.

Comment: question is about WPF not WinForms

Answer (score 1):

Instead of MouseLeftButtonDown you can use PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown evet to acheive your requirement.

Regards,
Riyaj Ahamed I